# React native with Redux | How filter data and keep the initial data in reudx state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

I implement a simple search functionality for my mobile app using React-Native & Redux, I fetch data from API and save them in my redux store, so when app is running, I already have a list of items.

Now I have a searchbox and I want filter the current list based on the keyword, since the list already getting the data from redux store, I persume that I need to apply the filter to the same property, but then how can I keep the initial one which I already got from API?

These are my actions :

```
import { GET_CRYPTO_DATA, FILTER_CRYPTO_DATA } from './types';

export function GetCryptoData(data){
  return {
    type: GET_CRYPTO_DATA,
    payload: data
  }
}

export function FilterCryptoData(filteredData) {
  return {
    type: FILTER_CRYPTO_DATA,
    payload: filteredData
  }
}
```

So first one will have all the data, and second one will have `filteredData`

This is my reducer :

```
import { GET_CRYPTO_DATA, FILTER_CRYPTO_DATA } from '../actions/types';

export default function(state= {}, action){
  switch (action.type){
    case GET_CRYPTO_DATA:
        return [...state, action.payload]
    case FILTER_CRYPTO_DATA:
        return [...state, action.payload]
    default:
        return state;
  }
}
```

and this is where I use combineReducers :

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

import CryptoDataReducer from './CryptoDataReducer';

export default combineReducers({
    cryptoData : CryptoDataReducer
})
```

I think something is wrong with the way that I updating the store. Can anyone help me with this?

**UPDATE**

Let me share with you my child components maybe make it more clear, so this is what I render in my parent component :

```
render() {
return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <HeaderComponent />
      <SearchComponent search={this.handleSearch} />
      <CryptoListComponent myList={this.props.cryptoData}/>

    </View>
);
}
```

As you can see I have a `<SearchComponent search={this.handleSearch} />` component which have a textbox and a button, what this one do is just pass me the keyword that user input for filtering the data. and in my `this.handleSearch` I will filter the data like this :

```
let filteredData = []
handleSearch = (keyword) => {
  let result = []
  if(keyword===''){
    filteredData = this.props.cryptoData
  } else {
    this.props.cryptoData.map(item => {
        if (item.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(keyword.toLowerCase())) {
            result.push(item)
        }
    })
    filteredData = result
  }
}
```

So I do have `filteredData` now, I tried to pass this as props to my `CryptoListComponent` component, but I always get empty list, but when I pass my redux store props `this.props.cryptoData` it will show all the list, so now what I don't know is to how to have my filtered data in the list when user input something and also have all my data when text box is empty.

I hope I explained clear enough this time.

Comment: If you don't need to share the filtered list across components there's no real point in putting it in the store.

Comment: @DanielLizik Well, I get all the data in parent component and send them as props to a child component which only render the list.

Comment: @EmadDehnavi not sure what that has to do with Daniel's comment. Unless that filtered list needs to be shared between unrelated components, you might as well do the filtering within the parent component and pass the filtered list to the children, rather than save the filtered ones in the store and get them from there. E.g. in the parent which is connected to the store, just render `<ChildComponent items={this.props.cryptoData.filter(/*some filter function based on user's search*/)}/>`, or do the filtering in some component function then have `<ChildComponent items={this.getFilteredItems()}/>`

Comment: @Jayce444 I Update my question, what I really not get it is how I suppose to have both filtered data and whole data using one props based on user input.

Answer (score 0):

I know that Redux State is the single source of truth, but I think in this case, we need to have a component level state as well which is only visible to our parent component, so thanks to this [article](https://medium.com/@yaoxiao1222/implementing-search-filter-a-list-on-redux-react-bb5de8d0a3ad) I added a component state to my parent component like this :

```
 state = {
    currentlyDisplay : []
 }
```

and based on the user input I will update this state, so if search box is empty I will update it with Redux Application Level state (mapped using mapStateToProps) and if user try to filter, I will update it using the filtered data, so in this case I can pass the `currentlyDisplay` to my child component which will render the list. This approach give me what I needed, I share this in case if someone needed. Let me know if there are better way to reach to the same result, I will happy to learn.

Comment: Another alternative solution is storing `keyword` in the state of parent component, and computing `filteredData` inside `render` instead of `handleSearch`